# Google maps postback in IE when info window is maximized

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an info window that I have 2 images on and i want to hide and show alternatively based on the user clicking an  tag.  This works fine when the window is in its normal state.  When I put the same HTML in the Maximized content it cause a postback in IE only.  Firefox works fine.

Here is my js and markup.  Can anyone suggest how to stop the postback in max window?

Funciton to show and hide:

```
> function ShowImage1() {
>     $('#Image1').show();
>     $('#Image2').hide();
> 
>     // Stop event handling in IE
>     return false; }
```

HTML in info window normal size:  (Exact same HTML for max window jsut with bigger hieght and width)

```
<div style="width: 240px; height: 180px;" id="MyInfoDiv">
<a onclick="ShowImage1();" id="Image1Btn" href="#">Image1</a>  
<a onclick="ShowImage2();" id="Image2Btn" href="#">Image2</a><br/>
<img style="width: 240px; height: 140px;" id="MapSiteImage" src="../../Image1.jpg"/>
<img style="width: 240px; height: 140px; display: none;" id="Image2" src="Image2.jpg"/></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the href attribute from the anchor and ie will not cause a postback